# pass select statement as IN parameter in Oracle function

Tags: sql, oracle

I have Oracle table function that accept one IN parameter.

e.g.

```
select column_value from table (my_table_fn('any value')   )
```

so I can pass a select statement as well like this one select col from tbl.

How can I pass it with WHERE clasue? I need to use single quotes like select col from tbl where col = 'aaa'.

I can not do this

```
select column_value from table (my_table_fn('select col from tbl where col = 'aaa' ')   )
```

Comment: Don't use dynamic SQL and pass unsanitised queries to functions as that is how your code becomes vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double the apostroph character inside string literal:

`select column_value from table (my_table_fn('select col from tbl where col = ''aaa'' ')   )`

(Another thing is that you should probably choose some solution to prevent SQL injection vulnerability - for example using some kind of prepared statement - but from your question it is not clear to me what is your technology stack around your problem so I cannot give more concrete advice.)